# How to pass multiple value in one query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid. there is multiple values in the grid. suppose there is candidate Id column in grid and there is check box in each row. I want to select multiple values of candidate Id  through check box and pass this multiple selected values in the single query string to another page after passed it i will split the values using `split()` function and keep in array. because i have to perform some operation on target page using this multiple candidate ids. please give to some solution for this problem.

There is my grid. ***i have not include check box in this code***

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdReq" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"    CssClass="SimpleGrid" OnRowDataBound="grdReq_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="CandidateID" HeaderText="Candidate Id" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Candidate Name" HeaderText="Candidate Name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Current Organization" HeaderText="Current Organization" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Current Designation" HeaderText="Current Designation" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Overall Exp" HeaderText="Overall Exp" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Qualification" HeaderText="Qualification" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You seem to have it all covered, apart from actually typing it, is there a problem you cannot solve?

Comment: Check this http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp

Comment: Thanks Guru Kara...i'll see

Comment: Is the problem finding out which checkboxes have been selected or assembling the query string with those values?

Comment: Yes Nerdwood,i have to select multiple check box then send to query string. please give me solution.

Comment: If you put a form around your fields, they'll get sent automatically when you click whatever button you have to submit that form (through GET).  Just make sure that the name (id?) of the checkboxes is the same but the value is the value that you want.  Your querystring will look like this, then: ?CheckBox=5&CheckBox=7&CheckBox=11.

Comment: i need a idea to send multiple values in single query string and how to access  from target page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i did something like that in the near past, procedure is:

1. loop through your page to find check boxes and add those who are checked, in string builder like:

```
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

           sb.Append(yourcheckbox);
            sb.Append(",");
```

on point of receiving you can split this using "," and you will have all the check boxes.

Good luck